# Voice recognition based on signal/spectrum analysis

Tags: c++, signal-processing, fft, voice-recognition, libav

I'm working on a solution to recognize an audio word by comparing the signal and spectrum.
To decode audio, I use libavcodec and libavformat and I use 1 reference word and compare to other.
**Example:**

```
# Must return true
./vrecog --file_ref chocolat.wav --file_cmp chocolat_2.wav
# Must return false
./vrecog --file_ref chocolat.wav --file_cmp banana.wav
```

**My step:**

1. I put the signal in a std::vector
2. I transform the signal into spectrum with [Fast Fourier Transform](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#C.2B.2B)
3. I calculate the [min, max, average, std_deviation, variance] of my spectrum
4. I use the values in step 3 to calculate a [correlation coefficient](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-find-correlation-coefficient/)

Is the reasoning correct ? The coefficient is always neer to 1 and I don't know what can I use to efficiently comparing data to says if the words is the same or not.

**These are my plots:**
*Signals (chocolat, chocolat_2 and banana):*
[image: chocolat signal][image: chocolat_2 signal][image: banana signal]
*Spectrum (chocolat, chocolat_2 and banana):*
[image: chocolat spectrum][image: chocolat_2 spectrum]
[image: banana spectrum]

We can easily see that the signal and spectrum seems near for both "chocolat" words, but I'm not able to get a percentage of similarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For signals, this is typically done via the cross-correlation function (of two signals) which is very similar to convolution. As such, it can be mathematically done via the FFT, which is specifically designed to be efficient. Once you take the correlation function, you can decide what threshold you want to be a "match", etc. For more information I'd read up at: http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookcpdf/c13-2.pdf since what we're talking about is pretty math heavy and was taught across a few weeks in one of my college courses.

Comment: Thank you for the PDF, I have also try to calculate correlation on the spectrum that contain *complex* numbers but sometimes the result was not in [-1:1]

Comment: I assume you're talking about the correlation coefficient, are you doing this properly for imaginary numbers (taking the conjugate)?

Comment: yes I'm talking about the correlation coefficient. When I try, I doing this: `corr(a, b) = ifft(fft(a_and_zeros) * conj(fft(b_and_zeros)))
` like on to this [post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-do-i-implement-cross-correlation-to-prove-two-audio-files-are-similar)

Comment: Ok, so you're talking about the cross-correlation equation then. To get a number in the range [-1:1] you need to divide by norm(a) * norm(b) which in this case is |a| * |b|.

Comment: `ifft(std::valarray<std::complex<double> >)` return me a `std::valarray`. I don't understand what to divide and how to get one value between the range. I have to divide the sum of complex number in my returned array by the product of the real and imaginary part of the sum ?

Comment: @ThibautB.: I have quite a bit of problems parsing that last comment. It gives me the impression that you're struggling with both C++ and math. So this is a bit of a guess, but I suspect that the problem is that you didn't realize that the cross-correlation gives you a _signal_. In particular, the cross-correlation is a function of the time-shift between the inputs `a` and `b`. That's why it is so useful: you find the maximum value of the cross-correlation signal to find the best overlap of `a` and `b`.

Comment: @MSalters, I'm apologize, is the first time that I have to deal with signal processing, so I'm a little bit lost. If I understand, `ifft(fft(a_and_zeros) * conj(fft(b_and_zeros)))` give me a signal. But I just can't figure out how to use this *signal* to say if "b" is the same word as "a".

Comment: @ThibautB.: The position of maximum of this signal says: "if b appears in a, then it appears at this time offset". The value of the maximum then needs to be divided by `norm(a)*norm(b)`.

Comment: @MSalters, So I iterate on the `ifft array` to find the maximum and get the offset but `a` and `b` are array, I can't divide maximum value by a multiplication of array. Maybe I confuse two things but I do not know what.

Comment: @ThibautB.: Do you know what we mean by `norm()` ? The norm of an array isn't an array but a scalar value.

Comment: @MSalters, I guess my confuse come from it. For me, the norm() is the square magnitude of my complex number. So if I divide maximum of `ifft` array by the norm of my two initial signal, I will have a percentage ?

Comment: @ThibautB.: The easiest way to think about this is to consider what would happen if you would amplify either A or B (i.e. multiply either signal by a constant value c). The FFT is linear, so `fft(c*A)=c(fft(A)`. Should amplifying affect the outcome of the detection.

Comment: @MSalters, Yes but if you say louder exactly the same word, it should not affect the correlation coefficient. Theorically, correlation should be the same between (A and A), and (A and A*constant).

Comment: @ThibautB. what I would have said has mostly been covered. But maybe this will clarify a bit. Imagine `a` and `b` are both vectors of length `m`. Then `norm(a) * norm(b)` is a scalar value which represents the largest value of the dot product of the two vectors if the angle between them were 0. This makes sense if we look at the dot product equation `a ⋅ b = |a||b|cos(Θ)`. basically for any time-shift t in the convolution we are finding the dot product between `a` and `b` in N-space. By dividing by `norm(a) * norm(b) = |a||b|` we normalize to have cos(Θ) which is guaranteed to be [-1 1].

Comment: I'll clarify than N-space is the signals when they are 0-padded, but for the sake of the example (both the dot product and norm(a) * norm(b)) are unaffected by 0-padding.

Comment: @samuelnj, thank you for your clarification, I will try to apply this and get my wanted answer (true/false) :)